# On Power Set of Naturals and Cantor Space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $A\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be any subset of naturals, the charasteristic function of A is for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\chi_{A}(i) = \begin{cases} 0 & i \notin A \\ 1 & i \in A \end{cases}$$

I would like to show that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and the Cantor space $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ is homeomorphic with the function for each $A\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ $\phi(A)=\chi_{A}$.
Surely it is bijection if we take any $f\in\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ and define $B=\{x\in\mathbb{N} : f(x)=1\} $ and $\chi_{B}=f$  but how can I show that $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous ?

Comment: How are you defining the topology on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: there is a product topology @Hayden

Comment: @Woodx: No, there is not: $\wp(\Bbb N)$ is not a Cartesian product. There is of course a product topology on $\{0,1\}^\omega$, but that is not the same set as $\wp(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: so how can I introduce a topology on P(N), actullay what I proceed is correct? if so how can I show the continuity for both side? any hint would be aprreciated @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: The simplest way is to use the map $\varphi:\wp(\Bbb N)\to\{0,1\}^\omega$ that takes $A$ to $\chi_A$: let $$\tau=\left\{\varphi^{-1}[U]:U\text{ is open in }\{0,1\}^\omega\right\}\,;$$ since $\varphi$ is a bijection, $\tau$ is a topology, and $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: so I guess we will say that $\phi$ is a homemorphism because it is bijective and OPEN? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: It’s a homeomorphism because it’s bijective, and we’ve defined $\tau$ so that $\varphi$ is both continuous and open.

Comment: thank you so much sir @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Woodx: You’re very welcome.